# Is there a way to find the child of a div and round the corners of a video frame? (Agora)

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my html, there is a video streams div, where the javascript puts the video containers and the displayed videos. I can't figure out how to round the corners of the boxes or put any CSS in. JS: [video script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Crazygird/tmsvideochat/main/main.js) Html: [image: html]

Comment: Please do not include pictures of code. Instead, add the code (as text) directly into your question.

Comment: Is this helpful? [CSS Child Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Answer (score 0):

With CSS you could use the following:

```css
#agora-video-player-track-cam-ce8174e7 video {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could target the class instead if you know you'd like the style change to apply to all of your video players:

```css
.video-player video {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Agora creates a new id every time a new user joins.

Comment: Hmmm, if you would want to target the class instead (if you know you'd want the same style change for all video players) you could try that instead.